# what's wrong with this (simple) sql Transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

the "else" section is always executed in the sql, any idea why?

```
use myDB
GO


begin TRANSACTION
go
declare @rowtoalter int =1

update myTempTable set name='newName' where userid=1

if(@@ROWCOUNT=@rowtoalter)
begin
    commit
    print N'yes it works'
end
else
begin
    rollback
    print N'nooo'
end 

GO
```

Comment: What does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTempTable WHERE userid=1`S give?

Comment: The update is obviously effecting more or less than 1 row

Comment: Print out `@@ROWCOUNT`.  My guess is it's not to equal to 1, meaning that the update didn't affect any rows

Answer (score 4):

You are altering less than or more than one row because you have zero or 2+ rows for `userid=1`.  What does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTempTable WHERE userid=1` give?

I've just tested where I update one row *exactly* and I get "yes it works"

Answer (score 0):

why not just incorporate the check right into your update:

```
declare @rowtoalter int =1

update myTempTable set name='newName' where userid=1
and (select count(*) from myTempTable where userid=1)=@rowtoalter
```